# Mac Terminals Shows Two Different Versions of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

When I type the line `python3 --version` into my mac terminal, it comes up as `3.7.6`. If I type the same line in VSCode's terminal, I get `3.7.7`. I wouldn't have thought it much an, except I can't import tensorflow on the `3.7.6` version which seems to also be causing issues with Jupyter since Anaconda runs it off Mac's terminal.

`brew install python` registers `3.7.7` as installed on the terminal, but even after re-installing and forcing the terminal closed and re-opened it still registers `3.7.6`. Any insight into the problem would be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was already written the problem is that you have two versions of python installed. And the version that is listed first in the `PATH` environment variable is used. In your default shell (probably `bash`) one path to python is used, in the terminal run from VSCode another `PATH` is used. You can check this by running `echo $PATH` command in both places and checking for difference.

The solution is to be careful with versions of python installed on your system and sometimes this is not easy.

I would suggest to use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for python version management. After the installation you will be able to easily switch between versions. Also it allows to easily install new versions and the most important that it does not conflict with system python installed on MacOS or with python installed with brew.

In your specific case with pyenv you can choose which version should be used globally for all applications (including bash sessions run in Terminal).

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have 2 versions installed. One from IDE(VSCode-3.7.7) and one from your own install(from the terminal-3.7.6).

Just uninstall  the 3.7.6 version, download and install a version that is compatible with tensorflow.

Or you can create a new virtual environments for python with conda.

Answer (score -1):

You have to know that Python in Mac environment has many bugs and often you will run into libraries issues or even problems with Python itself. This said I suggest you to download the newest version of Python you can find on the official site https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/, uninstall everything you can find about old Python versions on your Mac, then install only the last one you get to find.

Anyway personally I always run into issues with **VSCode** and Python because of imports! I suggest using **PyCharm** community version (if it is not a problem for you, but consider that it is 100% free and cross-platrform!). Personally I use **tensorflow** online on **google colab** platform, at least give it a try!

Comment: -1 Sounds like plain old FUD to me.  The language itself has no particular bugs on macos and this is a needlessly worrying statement.  What is true is that older macos come w a bundled Python 2.7 best left alone.  And, of course, if one does multiple installs like the OP things can go awry, but it’s neither rocket science nor mysterious voodoo if you reason based on PATH and configurations.